# Property 'role' does not exist on type 'AdapterUser'.ts(2339)

Tags: next-auth

I a currently working on a T3 project with NextAuth. I would like to access role when using UseSession.

```
interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: DefaultSession["user"] & {
      id: string;
      // ...other properties
      role?: ROLE
    };

  }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {

  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: user.id,
        role: user.role,
        // role: user.role,
      },
    }),

  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
};
```

My problem is that when I add role: user.role, it gave me this error: Property 'role' does not exist on type 'AdapterUser'.ts(2339) any

It gave me an error but it works on the frontend of my project. This is how I access it:

```
const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

sessionData?.user.role
```